# A Short Video to Explain Causal Inference to Non-Technical Audiences

Tags: references, causality, communication

I thought this question might be too much like a shopping question so I initially asked in [Ten Fold](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/65133449#65133449), but it was [suggested that I ask here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/65135899#65135899). Here is my original question:

> Anyone have suggestions on short videos I can send clients that explains causal inference? It seems like a difficult subject to reduce to a handful of sentences.

I cannot assume that my clients have a lot of time to spend on understanding causal inference the way that I do, and I cannot assume that they have any understanding of university-level mathematics (e.g. mathematical statistics or graph theory). But my clients are sometimes interested in it. I just need to distill the subject into a short introduction. I love McElreath's [Science Before Statistics: Causal Inference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KNPYUVmY3NM) but it is far too long and too technical.

What I need is a video around 5 minutes (maybe 10 minutes max) that I can send to the client to digest. The goal of such a video would be to communicate:

1. What is causal inference?
2. Why does causal inference help us make decisions under uncertainty?
3. How they would need to participate in helping form the causal assumptions of the modelling.

An accurate, concise, and clear explanation for a non-technical audience would provide tangible value in my communications.

Comment: +1 but community wiki, I guess?

Comment: @User1865345 I would be in favour of this being a community wiki.